# Import mixin into add-on in Ember cause "Uncaught Error: Could not find module"

Tags: javascript, ember.js, mixins, add-on

I am doing the following in my `addon/component/my-component.js`:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import layout from '../templates/components/my-component';
import myMixin from '../mixins/my-mixin';

export default Ember.Component.extend(myMixin,{
    layout
});
```

However doing this gave me
`Uncaught Error: Could not find module foo/mixins/my-mixin imported from foo/components/my-component`

The path of `my-mixin.js` is `app/mixins/my-mixin`.

How do I import my mixin, given the above structure? Thank you.

Comment: try `../mixins/my-mixin.js`

Comment: there is typo in import statement `import myMxixin` instead `myMixin`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`my-component.js` file is in `addon/component` directory, so placing `my-mixin.js` file in `addon/mixins` directory will solve your problem.